# Apache Camel RoutingSlip recursively send the message to the same endpoints

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I've been using RouteingSlip to send the messages to different endpoints which are specific to the particular message. Following is how I define RoutingSlip in RouteBuilder.

```
 for (TransitionTarget state : children.values()) {
                List<Transition> transitions = state.getTransitionsList();
                RouteDefinition routeDefinition = from("activemq:queue:" + state.getId() + "?asyncConsumer=true").to("bean:" + state.getId() + "?method=process");
                RoutingSlipDefinition<RouteDefinition> routingSlipDef = routeDefinition.routingSlip(header("MySlip"));
                routingSlipDef.setIgnoreInvalidEndpoints(true);}
```

Following is how I initially send the message to Start endpoint(I'm using ActiveMq)

```
template.sendBodyAndHeader("activemq:queue:HasReported",event,"MySlip","activemq:DarkDevice,activemq:HasAnomalies");
```

But when I run the program it seems the messages are recursively send to the "DarkDevice" and "HasReported" activemq endpoints. What I'm expecting is it should send the message only one time to particular endpoint.

Comment: I think you need to give more info than that. Is your bean doing anything special? Are you logging? Check the logs? A simple test: context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:in").routingSlip(header("dest"));
                from("direct:a").routeId("A").log("${body}");
                from("direct:b").routeId("B").log("${body}");
            }
        });
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:in", "myBody", "dest", "direct:a,direct:b");
        Thread.sleep(2000); works fine

Comment: I figured it out why it is recursively send the messages to those endpoint, because in each Route it send the message to both endpoints (activemq:DarkDevice,activemq:HasAnomalies) in parallel which is expected to be sequential.
 I wanted to send the message sequentially and ones it is send to the , Let's say DarkDevice activemq the relavent Route for the DarkDevice should omit the activemq:DarkDevice from the RoutingSlip.